# Discrepancy in nested flexbox overflow between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a table which contains drop-downs for each element (essentially an accordion), however I had wanted to continue using an html `table` as it is useful in generating nicely laid out column sizes. In the process, I have come across a discrepancy between flexbox overflows between Firefox and Chrome, that I cannot seem to fix.

I created a simple example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xzdli), and I added a code example below.

In Firefox, clicking the "click here" button to open the dropdown does so as I would have expected (the desired behavior), however in Chrome the content that should be hidden still shows up.

One fix I have already found is simply setting `display: none` and then `display: flex` when open on the wrapping div element in each dropdown, however I would ideally like to keep the animation where the contents inside of the dropdown appear attached to the bottom.  Additionally, setting `display: flex` on the dropdown `td` element allows the animation to work, but seems to override the `colspan` attribute, pushing all of the content into the first column.

Is this a known difference with a specific workaround, and if so how might I fix this? or might I be using a flexbox badly?

```js
let active = false;

function handleClick() {
  active = !active;
  if (active) {
    document.getElementById("tr").classList.add("active");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("tr").classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.tr {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: ease height 0.3s;
}

.td {
  height: 0px;
  transition: ease height 0.3s;
  column-span: 50px;
  /* 
    Uncommenting the line below allows for the dropdown in Chrome,
    but it then forgets about the colspan on the td element.
  */
  /* display: flex; */
}

.active {
  height: 150px;
}

.active .td {
  height: 150px;
}

.div1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.div2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
      <th>col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="handleClick()">
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td style="cursor: pointer;">click here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr" class="tr">
      <td colspan="3" class="td">
        <div class="div1">
          <div class="div2">
            stuff
            <input />
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```